# Ng-view with ng-animate doesn't seem to animate

Tags: angularjs, css-transitions, ng-animate

I've got a div element with ng-view, that works perfectly fine. I've been trying to do a simple slide using CSS Transition, and it seems like all of my animation efforts are useless, and the elements just appear/disappear in a blink.
Tried both AngularJS 1.1.4 and 1.1.5, it doesn't help.
Ideas anyone?

Here's the code:

**home.html**

```
    <div ng-view ng-animate="'animate'"></div>
```

**animations.css**

```
.animate-enter, .animate-leave {
  -webkit-transition:all 2s ease;
  -moz-transition:all 2s ease;
  -o-transition:all 2s ease;
  transition:all 2s ease;
}

.animate-enter {
    left: -100%;
}

.animate-enter.animate-enter-active {
    left: 0;
}

.animate-leave {
    left: 0;
}

.animate-leave.animate-leave-active {
    left: 100%;
}
```

Comment: where's the controller?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a position:relative or position:absolute or even position:fixed to the .animate-enter,.animate-leave css block.

I setup a plunker to demonstrate this on ng-view http://plnkr.co/edit/eT2RyZm5bBjlLTOnAO8R?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

**Have you tried to change your home.html (ng-view tag) like this?**

```
<div ng-view ng-animate="{enter: 'animate-enter', leave: 'animate-leave'}"></div>
```

Comment: yup, doesn't seem to work. Also tried CSS Animations and it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Well sorry for the trouble everyone and thanks again for helping.

This is a code I edited from someone else, and as I was updating the local angular.js file for the latest unstable version, I eventually found out that home.html gets the online file (that was linked to the stable version) and not the local one.

That pretty much solved the problem :}